# What should I fix / look for if my mining rig say Accepted 0 of 0?

Tags: mining-hardware

[image: mining rig accepted rate]

I have been mining using this software for over an hour now, and I would expect to see returns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like my question was closed. Was mining ETH, and getting a value in the MHs, so therefor I expected to see an accumulation over time.

Comment: For questions about Ethereum, I would suggest that you try ethereum.stackexchange.com.